# Why isn't this code working? I am new and I really need assistance

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I am trying to make it so when the lt turtle collides with the circle turtles(the ones in the list) it draws a star. But when I run it and try it the turtle does not draw a star. Please run it and see that I am trying to make it so when my turtle collides with the circles the turtle draws a star.

```
import turtle
import random
screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.listen()
list=[]
lt=turtle.Turtle()
lt.penup()
lt.shape("turtle")
for i in range(10):
  x=random.randint(-250,250)
  y=random.randint(-250,250)
  st=turtle.Turtle()
  list.append(st)
for z in list:
  z.speed(1000)
  z.shape("circle")
  z.color("white")
  x=random.randint(-250,250)
  y=random.randint(-250,250)
  z.penup()
  z.goto(x,y)
  z.pendown()
def left():
  lt.forward(2)
  lt.left(10)
screen.onkey(left,"A")
def right():
  lt.forward(2)
  lt.right(10)
screen.onkey(right,"D")
r=195
g=20
b=50
screen.bgcolor(r,g,b)
def StarCheck(z):
  if abs(lt.xcor()-z.xcor()) <15 and abs(lt.ycor()-z.ycor()) <15:
    z.clear()
    lt.color("yellow")
    lt.begin_fill()
    for i in range(5):
      lt.forward(5)
      lt.right(145)
      lt.forward(10)
    lt.end_fill()
while True:
  r=r-0.20
  screen.bgcolor(r,g,b)
  lt.forward(1)
  for n in list:
    StarCheck(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you have a typo in your while loop. It should be

```
StarCheck(n) instead of StarCheck(z)
```

Below is the listing of your altered code.

```
import turtle
import random

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.listen()
list = []
lt = turtle.Turtle()
lt.penup()
lt.shape("turtle")

for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(-250, 250)
    y = random.randint(-250, 250)
    st = turtle.Turtle()
    list.append(st)

for z in list:
    z.speed(1000)
    z.shape("circle")
    z.color("white")
    x = random.randint(-250, 250)
    y = random.randint(-250, 250)
    z.penup()
    z.goto(x, y)
    z.pendown()

def left():
    lt.forward(2)
    lt.left(10)
    
screen.onkey(left, "A")
 
def right():
    lt.forward(2)
    lt.right(10)

screen.onkey(right, "D")
r = 0.9
g = 0.2
b = 0.5
screen.bgcolor('red')

def StarCheck(z):
    if abs(lt.xcor() - z.xcor()) < 10 and abs(lt.ycor() - z.ycor()) < 10:
        z.clear()
        lt.color("yellow")
        lt.begin_fill()
        for i in range(5):
            lt.forward(10)
            lt.right(120)
            lt.forward(10)
            lt.right(72 - 120)
        lt.end_fill()
        return

while True:
    r = r - 0.000002
    screen.bgcolor(r, g, b)
    lt.forward(1)
    for n in list:
        StarCheck(n)
```

I ran this code and a yellow star is created as the turtle goes over the white circles.

You might also want to refer [colormode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgcolor) for setting appropriate RGB values or color. I am using python 3.7.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for answering, you really helped me out. It did work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes that @MustafaHaider suggests and implies but I couldn't get your code to *work* in any real sense.  There's a lot broken:

As @MustafaHaider noted, if this is standard Python turtle, you'd need to call:

```
colormode(255)
```

If you're not using standard Python turtle, eg. the Repl site, you need to mention that in your question.  This makes no sense:

```
z.speed(1000)
```

The numeric arguments range from 0 to 10, though I suggest a symbolic argument like `"fastest"`.  This will eventually underflow and cause an error:

```
r=r-0.20
```

@MustafaHaider switched to a smaller increment but that's the same issue -- using a multiplicative reduction and `int()` wouldn't have this problem.  Did you really want the user to have the CAPSLOCK pressed on some systems:

```
screen.onkey(left,"A")
screen.onkey(right,"D")
```

If not, I suggest "a" and "d" instead.  There's a turtle method for this:

```
if abs(lt.xcor()-z.xcor()) <15 and abs(lt.ycor()-z.ycor()) <15:
```

it's called `distance()`.  This doesn't do what you want:

```
z.clear()
```

as `z` hasn't drawn anything.  You want `z.hideturtle()` and only call `StarCheck(z)` if `z.isvisible()`.  Below is my rework of your code that addresses the above issues as well as others I haven't mentioned and general style:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def left():
    player.left(10)

def right():
    player.right(10)

def StarCheck(enemy):
    if player.distance(enemy) < 15:
        enemy.hideturtle()

        player.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(5):  # a la @MustafaHaider
            player.forward(10)
            player.right(120)
            player.forward(10)
            player.left(48)

        player.end_fill()

r, g, b = 195, 20, 50

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor(r, g, b)

player = Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('yellow')
player.speed('fastest')
player.penup()

enemies = []

for _ in range(10):
    enemy = Turtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    enemy.shape('circle')
    enemy.color('white')

    x = randint(-250, 250)
    y = randint(-250, 250)

    enemy.penup()
    enemy.goto(x, y)
    enemy.pendown()
    enemy.showturtle()

    enemies.append(enemy)

screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.listen()

while True:
    r *= 0.9999
    screen.bgcolor(int(r), g, b)

    player.forward(1)

    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.isvisible():
            StarCheck(enemy)

screen.mainloop()  # never reached
```

This should be *playable* now.  There's more to do, e.g. replace your `while True:` loop with a function and timed event if this is standard Python turtle.

Comment: Hey, I revised my code before I saw this and I basically already got what I wanted, figured it out, but thanks for your answer, really appreciated it. I am new to python and currently I am only learning and trying to master python with turtle graphics